# What if bounty question gets closed?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I want to put bounty on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994150/hidden-features-of-xml-dtd-and-xml-schema). It already has 3 closing votes, what if it gets closed after starting a bounty ?

Comment: You want to put a bounty on a question that will have multiple correct answers? WTF?

Comment: no probs ..answer with most up-votes will be accepted as correct

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24653/how-to-handle-off-topic-questions-with-bounty
Moderators can revoke a bounty...

Comment: what if I answer a bounty question, and then a moderator closes it for whatever reason? who gets the bounty points?

Answer (score 6):

It won't. [Questions with a bounty on them can't be closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)

Comment: Bounties are (too) frequently set to prevent the question from being closed/migrated....

Comment: You have to wait 2 days before you can set a bounty. If the question wasn't closed by then, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Less of a problem on SO than SF....

Comment: @balpha: This one is. Its current score is -4, it has a single answer. Even the community at large is distancing themselves from it. Can't say that I blame them. I'd cast the fifth vote, but because bounty questions can't be closed ... well, obviously I can't. :)

Comment: If the community doesn't feel strong enough about it to close the question within two days, then so be it. In the (probably not too common) case where a bad apple question really falls through the net, you can still call for a moderator, as Shog9 points out.

Comment: ... which apparently is exactly what happened in this case, as I just see.

Comment: @balpha : WRONG! It is perfectly possible to flag questions with an open bounty...

Comment: @user2284570 NOT WRONG! It certainly wasn't when I wrote this answer more than four years ago. But it still is correct. You can indeed flag a question for closure (something that didn't exist back then), but it cannot actually be closed until the bounty is gone (either because it's awarded/expired, or because a moderator removed it).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to flag questions with an open bounty and get it closed. Just write the standard version of the flag in *`others`*. This is what I got for the followings : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125953/disable-or-redirect-linux-kernel-console-after-boot)

This make the only case were the lost reputation is refunded to the person who started the bounty (you see something like [+50    3 hours ago    bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982032/it-is-a-literature?tab=reputation&sort=post) on the reputation user tab).