# Correct procedure for dealing with off-topic questions with bounty

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/what-happens-to-a-bounty-question-if-it-gets-migrated)
>   [How to handle off-topic questions with bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24653/how-to-handle-off-topic-questions-with-bounty)
>   [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6237916/115845) is clearly off-topic and should be migrated to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. However, it has a bounty on it which means the vote-to-close/migrate feature is disable.

What's the correct procedure for dealing with this?

I have tried flagging it for moderators' attention as per [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/what-happens-to-a-bounty-question-if-it-gets-migrated/38822#38822), but the flag was promptly marked as invalid.

#### Clarification

I have read the questions listed above as *possible duplicates* and have even linked to one of then. Answers to all three questions more or less recommend the same procedure, i.e. *flag for moderator attention*.

That was what I did. However, the flag was marked as invalid costing me flag weight points!

Don't get me wrong, I'm not bothered about the points. But the fact that I've been penalised for it implies that I've done something wrong hence the confusion (and this question).

#### Conclusion

Considering Jeff's comments below and the other related questions, I'm shall assume that the **correct procedure is still to *flag such questions for moderators' attention*** and the reason why my submission was marked invalid was simply because the question is potentially on-topic.

Whether the said question is on/off-topic is debatable, but that isn't really the focus of this question.

I shall yield to the wisdom of the mods and move on.

Comment: What's the rush? It's already been around a week without anyone noticing it, and it's not *so* offensive that closing it can't wait until the bounty period ends.

Comment: I wasn't in a rush. I was just curious as to what the standard procedure is. Searching meta revealed the post that states I should flag for moderator attention, but the flag ended up being marked down; hence the confusion and this question.

Comment: Yes, the question is not _offensive_ so there's nothing to gain/lose from having it around. However, the fact that the OP has waited so long AND has placed a bounty on it shows that he/she is eager for a solution but is not aware that the question might get better responses on the correct site. Simply ignoring the question is neither beneficial to the OP nor the site.

Comment: I don't entirely agree this is a slam dunk for webmasters, personally. It's borderline but I would not say it obviously belongs there.

Comment: I was initially uncertain as well until I noticed that it had been around for a week without a single answer/comment. It's a reasonably sensible question, so I take it that it's just targeting the wrong crowd.